# Trying to keep an image contained on the left

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my site's logo. It sits in the upper left hand corner. On a lower resolutions, it looks fine. However, at larger resolutions, you can see the logo shift off to the right. How can I adjust my css to make this stationary, just to the left of the "Home" link?

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="headerright">
        <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
        <!-- snip -->
    </div>
</div>

.headerright {
    left: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 966px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some code since this question will not be of value to anyone if the site goes down, the url changes, etc...

Comment: @Mohamad -- Normally I am really good at adding code. This site just has a lot of complex and nested divs, all with their own styles and if I were to post the code, there would be a whole bunch of code, especially CSS styles.

Comment: Err... I don't buy that. It's very simple, actually. It's so simple I've done it for you. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to reward me by +1 to my answer. I actually explained the issue :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve it!

Change .headerright to this:

```
.headerright {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 966px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

and #nav to this:

```
#nav {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 30px;
    height: 79px;
    width: 906px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The container element, `headerright`, is declared with an `absolute` position and a `left` value of 140 pixels.

```
.headerright {
    left: 140px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

When you resize the window most elements will adjust to a new position except for the `headerright` layer (or other absolutely position elements). The `headerright`, which contains the logo, will always be 140 pixels to the left, causing it to be misaligned on smaller screens.

You need to centre the div. This will allow it to adjust its position as the window resizes. Remove `position: absolute; left: 140px;`.

```
.headerright {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 966px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `.headerright` to `position: relative;` and add `margin: 0 auto;`

See below:

```
.headerright {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then if you want to move the logo a little bit to the left, add this to `#logo`:

```
#logo {
    margin-left: -60px;
}
```